# Using jQuery to set input box title to value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, forms

I am creating input text boxes that will set its title attribute as its value when the page is loaded. When the user clicks on a textbox, its value will be cleared, and when the textbox loses focus, either the user entered value will remain, or the default value will take its place.

**Problem:** I cant seem to make the textbox's value to be set on page load. Changing the value on focus and on blur works well though. What is wrong?

#### jQuery code

```
$(function() {
    ///////////////////
    // Register Form //
    ///////////////////
    $(".splash_register_short_input, .splash_register_long_input").value = $(this).attr('title');
    $(".splash_register_short_input, .splash_register_long_input").value = $(".splash_register_short_input, .splash_register_long_input").attr('title');

    $(".splash_register_short_input, .splash_register_long_input").focus(function() {
        if (this.value == $(this).attr('title')) {
            this.value = '';
        }
    });

    $(".splash_register_short_input, .splash_register_long_input").blur(function() {
        if (this.value == '') {
            this.value = $(this).attr('title');
        }
    });
});
```

#### HTML code

```
<div id="splash_register_form">
    <input type="text" name="register_first_name" class="splash_register_short_input" title="First Name" />
    <input type="text" name="register_last_name" class="splash_register_short_input" title="Last Name" />
    <input type="text" name="register_email" class="splash_register_long_input" title="Email" />
    <input type="text" name="register_password" class="splash_register_long_input" title="Password" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're attempting to set a property that doesn't exist (`.value`) on a jQuery object. Use `$("[YourSelector]").val()` instead.

Change this:

```
$(".splash_register_short_input, .splash_register_long_input").value = $(this).attr('title');
$(".splash_register_short_input, .splash_register_long_input").value = $(".splash_register_short_input, .splash_register_long_input").attr('title');
```

To this:

```
$(".splash_register_short_input, .splash_register_long_input").val($(this).attr('title'));
$(".splash_register_short_input, .splash_register_long_input").val($(".splash_register_short_input, .splash_register_long_input").attr('title'));
```

Comment: Should I also use either `$(this).val()` or `this.value` but not `$(this).value` and `this.val()`?

Comment: @Nyxynyx, Correct. `this` refers to the HTML element. `$(this)` refers to the jQuery object.

Answer (score 1):

I think we need to enumerate here .each function should be used for assigning value to each textbox such as

```
    $(".splash_register_short_input, .splash_register_long_input").each(function(){
     $(this).val($(this).attr('title'));
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like that should work :

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
  $('input[type=text]').focus(function(){ 
    if($(this).val() == $(this).attr('title'))
    {
      $(this).val('');
    }
  });

  $('input[type=text]').blur(function(){
    if($(this).val() == '')
    {
      $(this).val($(this).attr('title'));
    } 
  });
});
```

But you can also [search for a jQuery plugin concerning "placeholder"](https://www.google.com/#sclient=psy-ab&hl=en&source=hp&q=jquery%20placeholder%20plugin&pbx=1&oq=jquery%20place&aq=1&aqi=p-p1g3&aql=&gs_sm=sc&gs_upl=1312l3765l0l5114l16l11l1l0l0l0l170l1317l5.6l12l0&fp=1&biw=1253&bih=751&pf=p&pdl=300&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.,cf.osb&cad=b).